# Can't create Cloud Composer environment on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to create a Cloud Composer environment to run Airflow on GCP. However, I keep getting this error:

CREATE operation on this environment failed x minutes ago with the following error message:
Composer Backend timed out. Currently running tasks are [stage: CP_COMPOSER_AGENT_RUNNING
description: "No agent response published."
response_timestamp {
seconds: 1631717057
nanos: 229000000
}
].

Does anybody knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known [insufficient permission issue](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/troubleshooting-updates-upgrades#the_service_account_of_the_environment_has_insufficient_permissions):

When creating a Cloud Composer environment, you specify a service account that runs the environment's GKE nodes. If this service account does not have enough permissions for the requested operation, Cloud Composer outputs that same error message.

The solution is to assign roles to both to your account and to the service account of your environment as described in [Access control](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/access-control).